# Brightness in the application

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I choose brightness in my app by this method

```
public void setBrightness(Context context, int progress) {
        float BackLightValue = (float) progress/100;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getAttributes();

        if (BackLightValue == 0.0) {
            BackLightValue = 0.01f;
        }

        layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
//        layoutParams.screenBrightness = progress;
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

    }
```

this code works, but if I go to another activity brightness settings go back to previous.

How can I change brightness in all application? or I must to restore it on oncreate method on all activities?